# How to use XPath to select multiple possible text values?

Tags: xml, xpath

I have to select rating codes out of a ratings tag similar to the one below, but only when the agency is 'SP' or 'SNP'.  Right now I have:

```
./ratings/rating/agency[text()='SNP'|text()='SP']/../code
```

This doesn't seem to be working though.  What am I doing wrong?

```
<ratings>
  <rating>
    <agency>SP</agency>
    <provider>SP</provider>
    <type>LONG TERM</type>
    <currencyType>LOCAL</currencyType>
    <description>SP Standard LT LC rating</description>
    <code>BBB+</code>
    <date>2011-09-07</date>
  </rating>
</ratings>
```

Thanks,

Jared

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The main thing is the union operator `|` which you've tried to use as an 'or'. Change it to `or`:

```
./ratings/rating/agency[text()='SNP' or text()='SP']/../code
```

Or more naturally,

```
ratings/rating[agency[. = 'SNP' or . = 'SP']]/code
```

In XPath 2.0, you can use a sequence:

```
ratings/rating[agency = ('SNP', 'SP')]/code
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `or` instead of `|`

```
./ratings/rating/agency[text()='SNP' or text()='SP']/../code
```